# Symfony2 Sonata EcommerceBundle failing to install from composer

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I have a new project and I want to try out sonata Ecommerce bundle. I removed all the vendors to do a clean composer install, but when I do `php composer.phar install` I get this error:

```
$ php composer.phar install
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.6.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.6.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.6.x-dev requires sonata-project/ecommerce 2.3-dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/ecommerce": "2.3@dev",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.*",
        "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "~0.11",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "ddeboer/data-import-bundle": "dev-master",
        "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "3.3.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "~2.6",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I do

```
    "require": {
        "sonata-project/ecommerce": "2.3@dev",
    },
```

I get the same problem... I tried, both, `2.3@dev` and `dev-master`. It didnt help. **But without this ecommerce require the composer installs without any errors..** What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you use all the `sonata-project` dependencies? Are they dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the dependencies by starting from a new <kbd>composer.json</kbd> file:

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition "2.6" "2.6.*" --no-interaction -v
```

I added the `"sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-master"` dependency and `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to the <kbd>composer.json</kbd> file. Then `composer update` worked perfectly.

Then I started adding the dependencies from your question but it failed with all the dependencies, so I think there is a compatibility problem between packages.

Here is the full <kbd>composer.json</kbd> file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

---

Edit: I was able to install the dependencies from the <kbd>composer.json</kbd> file from the question by:

- remove the `sonata-project` and `"knplabs/knp-menu": "2.*",` requirements
- add `"sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-master",`
- add `"minimum-stability": "dev"`

Comment: Thanks! Appereantly the bundle hasnt been updated for a while and is using some old bundle requirements...

Comment: @Dominykas55 I found what package caused the problem, see the end of my answer if you need all the packages from your question.